# How do I prevent jquery from crashing on fast transition in bootstrap 4 accordion?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/aaz15/dLnrsfty/

What I am basically trying to achieve (with success) is to deviate from the official bootstrap documentation (http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/), and  create two distinct divisions with their own purposes (and for styling purposes).

The problem that I am facing is when I click many times on the same or different controls. An error is thrown:

```
Collapse is transitioning
    at Collapse.show
```

Is there a way to do is in regular css, or maybe regular javascript without crashing jquery?
Thank you

Comment: I tried converting to snippet but it doesn't actually run because of partial markup, can you fill more of the html and get this working?

Comment: @SergChernata  I created a jsfiddle. Please check the update.

Comment: As a point of clarification, you're not "crashing" jQuery.  You're receiving an *intentional* notice from what appears to be bootstrap's javascript code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're aware that you're using the alpha version of bootstrap 4. This error gets thrown in the official docs as well; there's nothing wrong with your code.

When using alpha and beta versions you should expect bugs, breakage and strange behavior or switch to stable release like bootstrap 3.